# Rubbing Alcohol and Vinegar

Tags: rubbing-alcohol-isopropyl, cotton-swabs-q-tips, ear-canal, cotton-balls

When someone has water stuck in their ear canal one of the remedies is a cotton ball soaked in equal parts of rubbing alcohol and vinegar and placed in the affected ear(s). 
What how does the alcohol and vinegar work to remove the water?

Comment: This is potentially a chemistry question?

Comment: Could be. It's a little bit of both as its a medical remedy/treatment option and it had the chemistry component to it as well as how it work. If it makes more since there I can close this one and repost it there